# Если возвращаемый тип функции утвердительный type guard, значит это boolean?

Tags: typescript

Вопрос такой. Если используется  [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) как возвращаемый тип функции, то это значит что его тип всегда будет булевой?

Пример:

```
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}
```

Еще раз - если всегда в возвращаемый части функции прописана конструкция через `is`, то я так понял что это функция всегда должно вернуть булево значение. Верно ли это?

Comment: Да. [Посмотрите на ошибку](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgZwBZQLxQN4FgBQV9QIDucAtgFywCuAdgMbBwD2NuAvrrqJFAEJwAnACZpMuAlABmAGxCUYtBs1Y4OOTjkmLGLKInjIAFJGDzEKAD59BQgJSUTehLHNi8UARGBUBNKAFYAbnYgA)

Comment: @EzioMercer благодарю